# Dig shows external configuration?

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, bind, dovecot, mx-record

I'm already trying for 2 days to deal with an answer for this problem.

I have a virtual server somewhere and installed postfix/dovecot/mysql. It works somehow. I can login with Outlook with the created MySQL-Account.

But I can't send or receive Emails. I always get these answers:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. 
This is a permanent error. The following address failed:

"user1@mydomain.com":
no valid MX hosts found
```

And

```
 'savingbambi@notmydomain.com' am 21.11.2014 15:22
 Server error: "554 5.7.1 <savingbambi@notmydomain.com>: Relay access denied"'
```

I changed the named.conf.options and added a new zone file. I created the zone file and added a MX-Record. Anyway, the changes I made seem not to affect anything.

My zone file looks like this:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     mail.mydomain.com. (
                    1
                    10800
                    3600
                    604800
                    38400)
        IN      MX      10 mail.mydomain.com.
@       IN      A       46.38.124.67
mail.   IN      A       46.38.124.67
```

My named.conf.options

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        forwarders {
               8.8.8.8;
        };
        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on {any;};
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};

zone  "mail.mydomain.com" {
      type    master;
      file    "/etc/bind/db.mail.mydomain.com";
};
```

Despite what I configure or do. I get always the same result with dig (like if the data comes from other place bit not my zone file):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> mail.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7485
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mail.mydomain.com.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.mydomain.com.  6516    IN      A       46.38.124.67

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.com.       63046   IN      NS      dns1.kontent.com.
mydomain.com.       63046   IN      NS      dns2.kontent.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
dns1.kontent.com.       505     IN      A       81.88.34.28
dns2.kontent.com.       1575    IN      A       81.88.40.11

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 46.38.225.230#53(46.38.225.230)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 21 19:14:13 CET 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 147
```

Does some of the other zone files (db.0, db.127, db.255, db.empty, db.local, db.root) overwrite my configuration?

Please help. I'm not an expert (obviously :-() in this context.

**UPDATE**
Running named-checkconf -zj:

```
dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/bind/db.mail.branchconcept.de:7: near eol: unexpected end of input
/etc/bind/db.mail.branchconcept.de:8: ignoring out-of-zone data (branchconcept.de)
zone mail.branchconcept.de/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/db.mail.branchconcept.de failed: unexpected end of input
zone mail.branchconcept.de/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/mail.branchconcept.de/IN: unexpected end of input
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
```

My zonefile looks actually (after some tries and with the real values):

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     mail.branchconcept.de. (
                        2011091202
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400)
branchconcept.de.        IN      MX      10 mail.branchconcept.de.
```

I added these entries by my ISP, but it does not help:

```
*.branchconcept.de  DNS A-Re­cord   46.38.232.105
branchconcept.de    DNS MX-Re­cord (Prio­ri­tät: 10)    mail.branchconcept.de
*.branchconcept.de  DNS-AAAA-Record 2002:2E26:E869:0:0:0:0:0
```

Maybe I'll ask it: Given Postfix and Dovecot installed in a server with the domain name domain.com. How do I,

1. configure a zone file to get mails like username@domain.com?
2. what do I need to care about in postfix configuration (main.cf)?

I defined die subdomain mail.domain.com because I thought it is necessary to be defined. It is the case? Or it is not necessary and I need to define a zone file only for domain.com like @Shane commented? I'm getting crazy because I don't have a clue.

Comment: Giving us the actual domain name would go along way to allowing us help you.

Comment: Is `46.38.225.230` the server where you have BIND running? In your obfuscated config you have a zone `mail.mydomain.com` with an `MX` record at the apex (implying mail addresses ending with `@mail.mydomain.com` which refers to `mail.mydomain.com`. This all just looks a bit strange. Also, there are no `NS` records in this zone, which appears to be an outright error. Are you sure that the zone loads properly? Logs and/or `named-checkconf -zj` output may be helpful.

Comment: Did you create an `MX` entry in the `mydomain.com` zone, or just in this `mail.mydomain.com` zone?

Comment: Hi Shane, yes 46.38.225.230 is the ip of the vserver where dig is running. Actually, it is 46.38.232.105. I was not sure if I should post it. Anyway, I'm really not an expert (my profession is psychology :-)) at all --> It is possible, that I have a lot of errors. My Email-Accounts were mamnaged before by the company where I bought my domain but because I got a vserver, I decided to setup also a mail server. I executed the command for named-checkcon and got:

Comment: dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/bind/db.mail.branchconcept.de:7: near eol: unexpected end of input
/etc/bind/db.mail.branchconcept.de:8: ignoring out-of-zone data (branchconcept.de)
zone mail.branchconcept.de/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/db.mail.branchconcept.de failed: unexpected end of input
zone mail.branchconcept.de/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/mail.branchconcept.de/IN: unexpected end of input
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1

Comment: @ShaneMadden: I did follow a tutorial about setting up a mail server in a linux dist :-(. I'm sadly not an expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Despite what I configure or do. I get always the same result with dig (like if the data comes from 
>   other place bit not my zone file):

In your output I notice you have 2 dns servers.

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.com.       63046   IN      NS      dns1.kontent.com.
mydomain.com.       63046   IN      NS      dns2.kontent.com.
```

Your domain server is set to use dns1/2.kontent.com and not your configuration. Update the configuration for those dns server where you bought the domain name or switch it to your own nameserver.

```
*.branchconcept.de  DNS A-Re­cord   46.38.232.105
branchconcept.de    DNS MX-Re­cord (Prio­ri­tät: 10)    mail.branchconcept.de
*.branchconcept.de  DNS-AAAA-Record 2002:2E26:E869:0:0:0:0:0
```

You should also add A and AAAA records for the main domainname. not just *.domainname.ext.

bit off-topic, but a few recommendations for you.
The ip you are using does not have a reverse ip pointer set. It's recommended to set one, see this [website](http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a45/what-is-reverse-dns-and-do-i-need-it.aspx) for some background on what it is.

Secondly, to reduce the chances off your mail getting blocked or marked as spam, or people faking your domainname its recommended to set a spf record which lists the ip adresses which are allowed to send emails from under your domain. This can be done with a simple TEXT entry in the nameserver setup.

```
text = "v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ip6:abcd:ef12:34:5678::/128 ~all"
```

You also need to set an A record to your domainname. Right now www.yourdomain.com will resolve to an ip, but yourdomain.com will not. Create a A and AAAA record with your ip adresses with as name either
@ or branchconcept.de.

Furthermore your DNS TTL is set to 1 day. This means that any changes to a record will take a full day before its fully updated for clients (This might explain why you are still having issues right now, I would recommend a bit lower, perhaps 1 hour?).

As for your zone file this would be valid, however your domainname still points to the dns servers of kontent.com.

```
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.
$TTL    1h
@                   IN      SOA     mydomain.com admin.mydomain.com. (2014111401 1d 2h 4w 1h )
mydomain.com.       IN      NS      ns.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.       IN      A       46.38.124.67
mydomain.com.       IN      AAAA    2002:2E26:E869:0:0:0:0:0 
ns.mydomain.com.    IN      A       46.38.124.67
ns.mydomain.com.    IN      AAAA    2002:2E26:E869:0:0:0:0:0 
mydomain.com.       IN      MX      10 mail.mydomain.com.
mail                IN      A       46.38.124.67
mail                IN      AAAA    2002:2E26:E869:0:0:0:0:0 
*.mydomain.com.     IN      A       46.38.124.67
*.mydomain.com.     IN      AAAA    2002:2E26:E869:0:0:0:0:0
```

Edit: Little more investigation, your SMTP server does not seem to accept connections. 
Make sure that:
 - No firewall is blocking port 25 connections
 - check your postfix configuration file and look for inet_interfaces. 
 Make sure that it does not only bind to localhost, but also your ipv4 and ipv6 adress.

As for further configuration, verify your [receiving domains](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#mydestination) (mydestination in the postfix configuration file) and the domainname you will [send email](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#myorigin) from by default.

**Update 22-nov-14**
I tried installing postfix myself. What I did was the following:

```
yum install postfix -y
```

Then I edited the postfix configuration file:

- Edited mydestination, added my .com domain name. (seperated by comma's)
- Edited myorigin, set to my .com domain name.

Changed inet_interfaces to my public ip so it can be reached from the outside.
SMTP using mxtoolbox worked on the ip at this point.

I added the following DNSrecords:

```
mydomain.com   mx   priority 10    mail.mydomain.com
mail.mydomain.com A MY_IP
```

Now sending mail using telnet worked fine, however I could not receive email from another server or gmail. After looking at the address sendmail was connecting to I found that it was using the A record of mydomain.com. So after adding an A record of mydomain.com to my mailserver ip I was able to receive emails.

Since your MX records are correct and your mail server is now reachable, the last thing you should do is add an A record of branchconcept.de to your server ip. Then it should hopefully work.

I tried testing your mail server, but it said there was no known user for root nor for the email listed on your website (using the domain @branchconcept.de). You might want to check if you have users set up.

So in short you should at this point do 2 things:

- Set up an A record of your main domain name to the ip of your server.
- Set up usernames if not done yet.

You can test/debug mail delivery from another linux server if needed using sendmail.

```
sendmail -v username@yourdomain.com < message.txt
```

where message.txt is

```
Subject: Testing smtp.
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain

Hi there, just testing.
```

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Hi, changing the configuration by my ISP did not help. I'll try the other option. Actually, I don't know. can you give me a hint?

Comment: Honestly, the DNS looks fine to me. Online DNS tools find your MX record and nslookup finds your MX record. I can't though, telnet to port 25 of your email server.

Comment: I tried sending an email to you from my own domain (gmail based) and it did not return yet. Please do know that there are name server caches. It might take up to 24 hours for changes to actually take effect. My guess is that your current settings are correct however that some dns cache's might still not be updated.

Comment: Hm, I also check with dig  branchconcept.de MX and it is showing correct information. My Postfix is not running. After 1000 changes I don't exactly know what is wrong now. I decide to read this book and check in parallelel my postfix configuration http://www.postfix-book.com/toc.html. I think, I'm near to a solution. Thank you all for supporting and giving hints. I'll write the solution when I did finally get this running (or maybe an step-by-step tutorial :-)).

Comment: OK, good luck. BTW, that test email I send yesterday did come back later that day. It was refused by mx.kontent.com. So, that was a dns issue which should now be fixed. One thing you might want to check out, do you have port 25 open for connections? (not blocked by a firewall or ISP perhaps) see [this page](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%3amail.branchconcept.de&run=toolpage)

Comment: Updated my post with a bit more information. It looks like you just need to change your A domain record and you should be ready to receive emails!

Comment: Hi @user254948! I got it (almost) working. I can succesfully login. The Problem is, when I want to send/receive an email I get this messages:
1) Receiving
Nov 22 20:40:37 v22014111607821351 postfix/qmgr[21388]: 2905FBD40A: from=<Ruben.Lara@gmail.com>, size=5195, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 22 20:40:37 v22014111607821351 postfix/smtp[21506]: 2905FBD40A: to=<ruben.lara@branchconcept.de>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for branchconcept.de loops back to myself)

Comment: 2) Sending
Nov 22 20:40:37 v22014111607821351 postfix/smtp[21509]: 304CEBD40D: to=<Ruben.Lara@gmail.com>, relay=mx.kontent.com[81.88.40.21]:25, delay=0.09, delays=0/0.01/0.04/0.04, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mx.kontent.com[81.88.40.21] said: 554 5.7.1 <Ruben.Lara@gmx.de>: Relay access denied (in reply to RCPT TO command))

Comment: Hi, "mail for branchconcept.de loops back to myself" that error message is supposed to happen when you did not add branchconcept.de correctly to the main configuration file under mydestination. Could you show me the line mydestination of the potfix configuration file? about the sending of emails, it seems to use the relay mx.kontent.com while it should not be using a relay, did you configure a relay or is this happening automatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18901/discussion-between-ruben-and-user254948).